# Where sk = null clause gives an error when used in a query but not in a stored procedure in teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, rdbms, dbms, teradata

In teradata sql I get an error when I use

```
sel *
from table
where sk = null
```

However if I include this in a stored procedure and pass a null value in the parameter I don't.

```
replace procedure(In name Integer,...)
....
local = sel *
from table
where sk = name
......

Call procedure(name = null,...)
```

What is happening in both these cases? Shouldn't it give an error in the second case too? I understand we need to use **is null** in the first case but why does it work in the second scenario?